# Does the DELL U2713H support 2560 x 1440 over HDMI @ 60fps

Tags: display, resolution, hdmi, fps

I currently have a DELL U2713HM monitor with a Max resolution of 2560 x 1440.  What DELL doesn't mention on their website is this resolution is only supported via DVI-DL and DisplayPort.

The max HDMI resolution for the U2713HM is 1920 x 1080 @ 60fps.  You can force the monitor to accept HDMI at 2560 x 1440 @ 30fps but it looks rubbish (at least from my graphics card).

Due to in wall cabling I may need to hook up my computer to a monitor via HDMI, does anyone know if the DELL U2713H can display 2560 x 1440 @ 60fps via HDMI without any hacks?

Note: The cables I have are HDMI 1.4 so they support this resolution.  There are also other monitors out there that support 2560 x 1440 natively by HDMI (http://www.asus.com/au/Monitors_Projectors/PB278Q/#specifications)

Comment: This is not simply a Dell limitation, it is entirely a limitation on single link DVI and HDMI.  You have found the only real solution (30 hz) and if you want full resolution at 60hz you need to recable.

Comment: I believe HDMI (1.3 and above) does support 2560 x 1600 @ 60fps over a single link (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi#Version_comparison), its just whether the hardware supports.

Comment: If the monitor does not support HDMI 1.3 (sounds likely) then my comment still stands.

Comment: [Another forum link](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/19469568.aspx) on the same problem.

Comment: I have now solved this with a registry hack.. http://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible/756813#756813

Comment: I got it it to work on Windows at 55 Hz with the Intel driver: http://www.notebookcheck.net/2560x1440-or-2560x1600-via-HDMI.92840.0.html

Comment: This is a great question, it shouldn't be closed

Answer (score 4):

There is somewhere in Dell's specification that it has HDMI limited to FullHD even when HDMI 1.4 supports higher resolutions. I don't think you will be able to change that. I had also this monitor and I had to buy (10 euros) DisplayPort cable (since DVI is used by my second smaller monitor).

BTW: DisplayPort cables use to be very thin so it may not be so big problem to replace existing HDMI in wall.

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't find anywhere in any DELL documentation or the website that states this.  Provide me the link and I'll accept

Comment: I remember I read it somewhere... looks like here: http://superuser.com/a/226333/184761    (I know it's different model, but I believe the reason is same :) )

Comment: And also other high resolution models (made by Dell) has similar limitation: http://www.prad.de/en/monitore/review/2012/review-dell-u2713hm-part3.html

Comment: Thanks very much for that prad link, they reviewed the monitor I have and had the same problem, I looked again at the DELL documentation and couldn't see it stated anywhere and also the prad review for the U2713 and they don't mention the problem so I'm hoping its possible but would like to confirm it.

Comment: I have now solved this with a registry hack.. http://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible/756813#756813