# Conflicting information for connection a thunderbolt mac to DisplayPort on Dell U2711

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, displayport, macbook-pro-retina, thunderbolt

I've just picked up this monitor to take advantage of the resolution and extra screen estate.  Didn't realise it'd be such a chore trying to find the right adapter for it.  I've come across a lot of conflicting information, after calling the Apple store I'm even more confused.

I'm connecting it via HDMI at the moment but that doesn't hit the 2560x1440 that I bought it for.  Has anyone connected this monitor to a thunderbolt/minidisplay mac?  If so, could you please post a link to the adapter.

Many many thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be too localized. 

Comment: Thunderbolt is backwards compatible to DisplayPort. Hence the option to buy DisplayPort cables with a Thunderbolt Mac. The screen also has a DisplayPort input, so it should be obvious what to buy: A MiniDP-DP cable. (HDMI doesn't work because Apple considers this to be the 'TV' option maxing out at full HD)

Comment: @gronostaj *Too Localized* was one of the most misused close reasons. That's why it's gone.

Comment: @DanielBeck - That's exactly what I figured, then I spoke to Apple and it all went weird.  I've bought a cheap adapter, if it works fine the  I'll get a better one.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @SteveGreen - Why would you get a "better one" a cable is a cable.  Just because it has a gold connector instead of a connector doesn't make the quality any better.  Save your money, your cheap cable, is just as good as the one that costs 6x as much.  Anyone that says they can tell the difference between two cables is not telling you the truth.

Comment: @Ramhound - If that is the case then I thank you for saving me some cash :)

Comment: @SteveGreen - I will use the the following as a simple example.  `Monster Cables` they use "gold connectors" there 1/2 meter HDMI cable is very expensive.  You can go to a website like https://www.monoprice.com/ and spend 1/3 of the money for a cable 6x the length.  The same goes for most cables.  You just have to make sure you verify the support version of the HDMI specification.

Comment: @Ramhound - Maybe it's just the remnants of pre-hdmi cables then.  I remember audio/video having a better quality when a cable was better.  Although this is when co-ax awas the norm.  I thin it still holds true for speaker wire though.  Not sure.  But thanks for the info, it'll save me some cash :)

Comment: @SteveGreen - There might be some argument for speaker wires depends on several factors.  Of course my feelings towards the quality of audio/video might be different then yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These people](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1200813) apparently have made the connection you want, and they did it with [this adapter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/673985-REG/Gefen_ADA_MDP_2_DPF_Mini_DisplayPort_to_DisplayPort.html) and a DisplayPort cable, or a [cable like these](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246&cs_id=1024606).

That is, either:

- a DisplayPort (female) to MiniDisplayPort (male) adapter (and the monitor comes with a DisplayPort cable, I assume), or
- a cable with a DisplayPort end and a MiniDisplayPort end

I think the key is that you don't need anything specifically Thunderbolt.  DisplayPort cables can be used with Thunderbolt jacks, and DisplayPort can handle that resolution.

(Actually, though, so can HDMI: [HDMI with resolution 2560 x 1440 possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible) ...but Apple seems not to be using the full capability of HDMI.)

Comment: Thanks for the details!  I just bought one of these from ebay, cheap but hoping it'll do the job.  http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/300731715574?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649 I Love my mac but sometimes apple can be GAAAAH!.  Woman I spoke to on the phone - "We have thunderbolt ot ethernet cables...we have...."