# Can't create custom resolution using intel custom mode app in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, intel-graphics

I have a Dell XPS 15 with 3200x1800 native resolution. I'm trying to reduce it to 2560x1440 but that option isn't available by default and either is the option for custom resolutions. So I found how to do it by going to C:/Windows/System32/customemodeapp.exe which brings up a panel to create a custom resolution but when I enter in the desired resolution it says "The custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity". Now I tried 60,50,40,32,30 for the refresh rate but all gave me the same error. No idea what the problem is. Here's my specs.

```
Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600

Report Date:            2/18/2014
Report Time[hh:mm:ss]:      19:49:57
Driver Version:         10.18.10.3282
Operating System:               Microsoft Windows 8.1(6.3.9600)
Default Language:               English (United States)
Installed DirectX* Version:         11.2
Supported DirectX* Version:         11.0
Shader Version:         5.0
OpenGL* Version:                4.2
Physical Memory:                16287 MB
Processor:                  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4702HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
Processor Speed:                2195 MHz
Vendor ID:                  8086
Device ID:                  0416
Device Revision:                06

*   Processor Graphics Information   *

Processor Graphics in Use:          Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
GOP Version:            5.0.1032
Current Graphics Mode:      2048 by 1152

*   Devices Connected to the Graphics Accelerator   *

Active Notebook Displays: 1

*       Built-in Display        *

Monitor Name:           Generic PnP Monitor
Display Type:           Digital
Connector Type:         Embedded DisplayPort
Serial Number:          SHP13F8
Gamma:              2.2
DDC2 Protocol:          Supported
Device Type:            Built-in Display

Maximum Image Size:
Horizontal:                 13.78 inches
Vertical:                   07.48 inches

Monitor Supported Modes:
3200 by 1800 (60 Hz)

Display Power Management Support:
Standby Mode:           Not Supported
Suspend Mode:           Not Supported
Active Off Mode:                Not Supported

Raw EDID:
00 FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 4D 10 F8 13 00 00 00 00 
22 17 01 04 A5 23 13 78 0E DE 50 A3 54 4C 99 26 
0F 50 54 00 00 00 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 
01 01 01 01 01 01 CD 91 80 A0 C0 08 34 70 30 20 
35 00 5A C2 10 00 00 18 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FE 00 36 
52 47 57 30 80 4C 51 31 35 36 5A 31 00 00 00 00 
00 02 01 03 28 00 12 00 00 0B 01 0A 20 20 00 1B 


* Other names and brands are the property of their respective owners. *
```

Update. I tried using the DTD Calculator to edit the registry but it won't let me and I'm not confident adding the DTD directly to my registry is a good idea if anyone can confirm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force 2560x1440 resolution in Windows 8.1 on Dell XPS 15](http://superuser.com/questions/718244/how-to-force-2560x1440-resolution-in-windows-8-1-on-dell-xps-15)

Comment: chill dude. I deleted that one.

Comment: Or downvote my obviously more specific question. Annoying

Comment: Start `regedit.exe`, and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E968-E325-11CE-BFC1-‌​08002BE10318}\0000`. Check if there's any value called either `DTD_1` or `TotalDTDCount`.

Comment: Both exist. DTD_1 is (01 1d 80 18 71 1c 16 20 58 2c 1a 00 00 00 00 00 00 86 37 01). TotalDTDCount is (0x0000000 (0))

Comment: I changed the TotalDTDCount to 5 but I still couldn't add the custom resolution. There are 5 DTD values and the fifth is all 0's.

Comment: I used a DTD calculator to find the DTD of 2560x1440 which is (02 3A 00 18 A1 A0 2D 50 58 2C 25 00 55 50 21 00 00 1E) but that's 18 bytes and the other DTD are 20 bytes so I'm hesitant to try it.

Comment: [**Your drivers are clearly out of date.**](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23714&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%208.1%2C%2064-bit*&DownloadType=Drivers)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HDMI with resolution 2560 x 1440 possible?](http://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible)

Answer (score 1):

Different PC but similar adapter and problem (Intel HD Graphics 4000).

You can set custom resolutions via the "Graphic Options" menu that is available by right clicking on the Desktop.

Once you have configured the custom resolution, you'll need to reboot your PC before you can select this new resolution from the Windows screen resolution window.

[image: Intel Graphic Options menu]

[image: Intel Graphics Control Panel]

Comment: this is not possible and outputs the error: The custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity

Comment: @FalcoAlexander - You'll need to reduce the refresh rate until you are within the maximum bandwidth capacity.

Comment: Bandwidth of what? The Monitor?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander - No, the bandwidth of the graphics card.

Comment: I doubt this for some reasons: I'm running my computer with dual monitors. so exceeding the max. (Intel HD 4600) bandwifth should be related to the 2nd monitor and resolution+fps also....

Comment: 2nd: Intel states for my CPU internal graphics a Bandwidth of 1,2 GHz and a Monitor at 4k@60Hz consumes 0,5 Ghz plus 0,13 Ghz for a normal FullHD resolution@60 Hz

Comment: @FalcoAlexander - Does it work if you reduce the refresh rate?  I guess it really doesn't matter where the maximum bandwidth capacity is being exceeded but just that it is being exceeded.

Comment: I have the i7-6700k, with the HD520. The GPU has official Displayport 1.2 support. I have latest drivers installed. The motherboard vendor says for this motherboard that 4k@60hz is officially supported. And the custom resolution panel in Intel driver still won't let me enter any refresh rate above 30Hz while at 4k. "The custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity" Scratching my head here.