# connected QHD monitor to laptop using HDMI, resolution limited to FHD

Tags: display, hdmi

I have a laptop (MSI GE60) with FullHD screen and I want to connect this with a QHD monitor (2560x1440), but when I connect by HDMI I have FullHD as max possible resolution. I don't know how to set the UHD resolution. OS Windows 8.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Thats because windows knows your monitor, he doesnt know anything more than it. Like mine I have a Geforce GT 640M LE which is quite powerful and can render UHD too but look at this: http://upload7.ir/uploads//f9bb892891d542020404f1b1c662e107b24334aa.jpg

Comment: I need Windows :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the maximum resolution that machine can output over HDMI.

See http://service.msicomputer.com/msi_user/support/TechFAQdetail.aspx?formid=3076

Comment: Uff i have MSI GE60 2OC

Answer (score 0):

This could be the HDMI cable. You'll need at least a *High Speed HDMI cable* to support this resolution. Standard speed cables only support resolutions up to 1080p.

Comment: Still not work...

Comment: Not just the cable. All parts need to support it. Laptop, cable and monitor.

Answer (score 0):

[A lot of monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible) using HDMI 1.x have the resolution limited to FHD when receiving the image data through their HDMI port.

A workaround for this problem is using displayport (if the laptop has it) or an HDMI-to-DVI cable where you connect the DVI-part to the monitor. But make sure you use a Dual Link cable for this (DVI: 24 + 1 pins), because a Single Link (DVI: 18 + 1 pins) is limited to 1920x1200 which is again lower than the native resolution of your monitor.

[image]