# How to set high resolution on nVidia card?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, resolution, high-resolution

- gfx card: [nVidia GeForce GT 530](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-530-oem/specifications)
- monitor: [Samsung C27H711](http://displaysolutions.samsung.com/business-monitor/detail/1105/C27H711) (2560x1440, connected over HDMI cable)
- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit

Windows starts in 1920x1080, the Display Control panel applet shows that as maximum resolution.

If I define a custom resolution of 2560x1440 in the nVidia Control Panel and activate it, the picture is very blurry and the monitors OSD menu claims it is still 1920x1080.

The [nVidia release notes](http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/384.76/384.76-win10-win8-win7-desktop-release-notes.pdf) list 2048x1536 as the maximum supported standard resolution (I wonder when they'll add 4K modes, they are pretty standard if you ask me).
On the other hand the [GT 530](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-530-oem/specifications) home page lists: `Maximum Digital Resolution: 2560x1600` So it should work.

The question is: how to set things up to use the monitors native resolution of 2560x1440?

Comment: The card is from 2010, while HDMI v1.3 (that introduced support for 2560×1600p/60 Hz) is from 2006, so I doubt a too old version of HDMI is at fault. The HDMI cable came with the monitor so it should be good enough too.

Comment: Did you try a different HDMI (1.3) cable? Perhaps they didn't send a 1.3 with your monitor.  Are you running a Dell? Look at this 
https://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible  "There are many posts about limited resolutions on Intel chips."

Comment: @FredSavage187 The cable is OK, it works at top resolution with another PC.

Comment: Try using the DVI output on the GPU. The specs say "support for 1080p Blu-Ray discs over HDMI."  Under Dual-link DVI support, it says:  "Able to drive industry’s largest and highest resolution flat-panel displays up to 2560x1600 and with support for High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: create a custom resolution of 2560x1440 with Timing set to "CVT reduced blank"

Long: In  nVidia Control Panel I had to create a custom resolution of 2560x1440 at 60Hz with the *Timing* option set to "CVT reduced blank" instead of the default "Automatic".

Hints taken from https://www.notebookcheck.net/2560x1440-or-2560x1600-via-HDMI.92840.0.html